# Awaiting a method that is deeply nested on stack

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, async-await

Lets say at some point at least 10 methods are available at stack as not finished. Many of these methods are dealing with actions that make impact on UI. At this point, I would like to issue a Save command. Save command can finish successfully, or can fail. Based on the result, I would like to make different actions, and only then return execution to those methods that are left on stack.

Now, if I run Save command synchronously, there is no problem. I would like to execute Save command asynchronously, return the execution to message pump (UI), while all the code (methods) on stack should wait for SaveCommand to finish.

Now, as I have understood await, there is no guarantee that a call will be made on same thread (in my case UI thread). SO, I cannot just await the first method that was called (the parent of all other methods in stack), since if a different thread gets started, it will raise a UI exception (accessing UI elements from different thread).

So, how to handle this situation? Example code:

```
public bool PropertyName {get; set { MethodA(); // some code after  };}
public void MethodB() { MethodC(); // some code after  } 
public void MethodC() { MethodD(); // some code after  } 
public void MethodD() { MethodE(); // some code after  } 
// etc

void MEthodK()
{
    Save();
}
```

Comment: you should probably tell us what language/framework/etc you are working with

Comment: I have updated the question. those methods does not neccesserily have to be methods, they could be functions, it is just void for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to (asynchronously) wait for a method, just `await` the `Task` returned from that method:

```
public async Task MethodCAsync() { await MethodDAsync(); // some code after  } 
public async Task MethodDAsync() { await MethodEAsync(); // some code after  } 
async Task MethodKAsync()
{
  await Save();
}
```

This will cause a problem with your property setter, which now must be an asynchronous method:

```
public bool PropertyName { get; private set; }
public async Task SetPropertyNameAsync() { await MethodAAsync(); // some code after }
```

Comment: So, your suggestion is to await all methods, although I need to await only one? That was the first thought I have, but the tought itself made me step back. This would in reality mean that majority of my methods will be async... I was hoping that there would be some kind of awaitX method, that would immediately return control to message pump, not the previous caller, and when task is marked as completed, then the pump would return execution to right after the await keyword.

Comment: @Goran That's pretty much what this does, it just requires everything to be asynchronous for it to work.

Comment: I understand how async await works, but I just don't like the idea having it everywhere. Are there some performance concerns? Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Goran: Using `async` all the way up the call stack *is* the way `async` works. There aren't any real performance concerns. Alternatives include any other kind of [asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx), but all other patterns are far more complicated and still require you to change every method in the call stack in a far more drastic way than making them `async`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you call `ConfigureAwait()`, `await`ing a `Task` from a UI thread will always resume running your code on the UI thread.
You don't have to worry about it.

Comment: SO, in the code I have just added, what would be your suggestion for proper approach (to run MethodK without blocking the UI thread, and force all other methods (A-K) to wait for Save to complete?)?

Comment: @Goran: Make all of those methods `async`, and `await` them whenever you call them.